# httpClient.GetAsync() timeout exception, if application idle a long time

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, dotnet-httpclient, get-request

I developed `C# .net 4.6.1` application.
In the application I use `HttpClient` for communicate with our backend API.
Over time the application not sending the request to our backend (timeout exception is catched). The request is sent, after restart  application.

Here is the snippet of our code.

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    MyClass myClass = GetAsync().Result;
  }

  private static async Task<MyClass> GetAsync()
  {
     MyClassResponse myClassResponse = await TestHttpClient.GetMyClassResponse();
    return MyClass.Create(myClassResponse);
  }
}
```

```
public static class TestHttpClient
{
   private static HttpClient _httpClient;

   public static void Init()
   {
     _httpClient = CreateHttpClient();
   }

   public static async Task<MyClassResponse> GetMyClassResponse()
   {
      HttpResponseMessage response = await GetRequestAsync("https://....");
      return await ParseToMyClassResponse<MyClassResponse>(response);
   }

   private static HttpClient CreateHttpClient()
   {
      HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("token .....");
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
      client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000);
      return client;
    }

    private static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetRequestAsync(string url)
   {
        try
        {
           return await _httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(url));
         }
         catch (TaskCanceledException)
         {
          return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout);
         }
    }

    private static async Task<T> ParseToMyClassResponse<T>(HttpResponseMessage response) where T : MyClassResponse, new()
        {
            T myClassResponse;
            try
            {
                string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                myClassResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(content);
                           }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                myClassResponse = new T();
            }

            response.Dispose();
            return myClassResponse;
        }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: hello @aram could you share with us , the error message and code status ?

Answer (score 2):

A couple things I see:

First, your exception handler is ignoring the exception and throwing a new exception. Assign a variable to your `TaskCanceledException` and log that actual exception before you throw a new one. The inner exceptions might give you more information about what happened.

```
catch (TaskCancelledException e))
{
    Debug.WriteLine(e);
    //do whatever else
}
```

Side note: using `new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout)` is probably not the most appropriate thing. That makes it look like the server returned a [408 Request Timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/408). When that's not really what happened.

A timeout that would throw a `TaskCanceledException` is when the client sent the request, but no response was received from the server in the time expected (30 seconds by default).

If that's truly the kind of timeout happening, then you may have to look at something like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to verify that the request is actually being sent. Then you would have to figure out what's different between that request and the request sent once you restart the application.

For example, is your token expired and restarting your application requests a new one? (that *shouldn't* result in a timeout, but if the server code is poorly written it could)

Comment: Thanks for quick response.This error is produced only one of our customer. I'll try to install the Fiddler on their computer and will analyze the request. Today I'll add logging and will share error message and status.

Answer (score 0):

I added logging and got following error:

> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException · A task was cancelled.

```
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
TestHttpClient+<GetRequestAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
```

And I looked at the requests with using Fiddler, and got following results

1. In normal mode fiddler shows 2 requests

   - Result=200, Protocol=HTTP,  Host = Tunnel to, Url = api.example.com:443

     > **in SyntaxView   tab:** A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.
   - Result=200, Protocol=HTTPS,  Host = api.example.com, Url = /test
2. In failed mode Fiddler shows only 1 requst

   - Result=200, Protocol=HTTP,  Host = Tunnel to, Url = api.example.com:443,

     > **in SyntaxView   tab:** After the client received notice of the
     >   established CONNECT, it failed to send any data

I would like to make a correction. In reality, I use the Init() method like this.

```
public static class TestHttpClient
{
   private static HttpClient _httpClient;

  public static void Init()
  {
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= (SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | 
              SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | 
                                            SecurityProtocolType.Tls);
    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10;
    _httpClient = CreateHttpClient();
  }
}
```